# Tag dispatching to protect from interface changes

Tags: c++, boost

I am working on some application and need to make some architectural decisions. The problem I have is the lack of specification of the INTERFACE I will have to work with. 
Let's say that for the time being I only know the INTERFACE will have two functions, 'work' and 'print'. At the time being I can only guess what parameters these functions will require, and that most probably the parameters will be completely different (so, for example, I cannot have a container of function pointers to store these functions).

The project will probably last some time and during this time the INTERFACE I am using will get more and more specified (what I mean is that it can be changed very often). What I would like to achieve is to somehow protect myself from these changes, i.e. minimize the amount of work needed to be done when the interface changes. And also prepare myself for new functions which may appear in the INTERFACE.

I started thinking about some kind of mechanism in my code which would help me doing this. I want this mechanism to call the functions from the INTERFACE. I want this mechanism to be free from stupid endless if-else statements. And I want to have a mechanism which I could mock in the tests to separate from the INTERFACE.

I read about possible dispatching mechanisms, I read about metaprogramming, boost::hana, mpl. I read about storing functions in boost::variant or boost::any, and about passing tuples to functions and unpacking them with the help of index_sequence. But none of the solution was nice and elegant for me.

I invented something like this below, although it is also far from perfect. But I would like to ask you what you think about such approach. Is it OK in my case? Is it maintenable? Extendable? Elegant?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

struct work_tag {};
struct print_tag {};

// --- real functions of the INTERFACE ---
void doWork(int a, int b, string s)
{
   cout << a << ", " << b << ", " << s << endl;
}

void doPrint(int a, double d, double e, int f, string s)
{
   cout << a << ", " << d << ", " << e << ", " << f << ", " << s << endl;
}

// --- fake function for tests ---
void fakeDoWork(int a, int b, string s)
{
   cout << "this is a fake: " << a << ", " << b << ", " << s << endl;
}

void fakeDoPrint(int a, double d, double e, int f, string s)
{
   cout << "this is a fake: " << a << ", " << d << ", " << e << ", " << f << ", " << s << endl;
}

// --- my class, it will do some operations and call the INTERFACE ---
struct B
{    
public:
   B(auto funForWorking, auto furForPrinting)
       : m_funForWorking(funForWorking), m_funForPrinting(furForPrinting)
   {}
   template <class... Args>
   void request(Args... args)
   {
       dispatch(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
   }

private:
   template <class... Args>
   void call(work_tag, Args... args)
   {
      m_funForWorking(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
   }

   template <class... Args>
   void call(print_tag, Args... args)
   {
      m_funForPrinting(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
   }

   template <class TYPE_TAG, class... Args>
   void dispatch(TYPE_TAG type_tag, Args... args)
   {
      call(type_tag, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
   }

private:
   std::function<decltype(doWork)>  m_funForWorking;
   std::function<decltype(doPrint)> m_funForPrinting;
};

int main()
{
    // production code
    B b(doWork, doPrint);
    b.request(work_tag{}, 1, 2, "a");
    b.request(print_tag{}, 1, 2.0, 3.0, 4, "bbb"s);

    // somewhere in the tests
    B btest(fakeDoWork, fakeDoPrint);
    btest.request(work_tag{}, 1, 2, "a");
    btest.request(print_tag{}, 1, 2.0, 3.0, 4, "bbb"s);
}
```

I know this is not a perfect solution, because when a new function will appear in the INTERFACE I will have to modify the code of my class, add new overload of 'call', new member storing the new function, add new dispatch tag. But at least I am protected somehow from the changes of the parameters list of the existing functions of the INTERFACE (I will have only to change the calling place in the code).

Ideally I would like to get rid of the necessity to provide members for storing each function of the INTERFACE (somehow store the functions in a map and dispatch the call using the map) and also the necessity to provide the overload of 'call' for each method of the INTERFACE. But I don't know how to do this in my situation, when each function has different arguments.

Is there any better solution for doing this?

Comment: This smells of [premature generalisation](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureGeneralization) to me. I fear that in an effort get something that is future proof you are sacrificing the usability of your code. In order to use `B::request()` you have to find the right tag, and work out what the correct parameters are to pass because the signature of the function does not tell you anything.

Comment: Thank you Chris. Maybe you're right... I have to think about this more.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not a very helpful answer but I think it is hard to provide a good answer to this question without really understanding what `struct B` is for. What is it's purpose in life? What gives it cohesion? What is it trying to encapsulate? Perhaps in your real case `B` does other things other than just forwarding your call on to the function?

In your current design, in order to use `B` you need to have a deep understanding of the functions it contains so I don't think it is hiding any details of those functions. It could be replaced by:

```
struct B
{    
   std::function<decltype(doWork)>  work;
   std::function<decltype(doPrint)> print;
};
```

And the calling code would be:

```
// production code
B b{doWork, doPrint};
b.work(1, 2, "a");
b.print(1, 2.0, 3.0, 4, "bbb"s);

// somewhere in the tests
B btest{fakeDoWork, fakeDoPrint};
btest.work(1, 2, "a");
btest.print(1, 2.0, 3.0, 4, "bbb"s);
```

Comment: Thank you Chris. But in your approach I have to explicitly call 'work' and 'print'. This is exactly what I was trying to avoid. Maybe I wasn't very precise in my description of the problem. Let me clarify this a bit. What I wanted to achieve was to first have some general mechanism transforming some external, high level request to some general form of available request types (i.e. tags) and then passing them to a class performing the request on given platform. In other words I wanted to have an upper, middle and low level component separated from each other in some way.

Comment: The top component would be A, the middle would be B, and the low level would be C. I wanted the middle level component, B in my case, to be a translator, to only provide 'sendRequest' method and nothing else. Then the call to B's sendRequest method (from A) could directly be translated to call to low level C component's method. The top component (A) would have to specify the recognized (by itself) tag in the call to sendRequest, and of course provide the parameters (depending on the type of request).

Comment: Then the 'B' would dispatch the request by the tag (by overloading mechanism, not by if-else) and call the appropriate method of the lowest level component C, which would take care of all internal things related to actual processing the request on given platform. I wanted to have a clear separation of components: i.e. components receiving requests from external applications (A), and components taking care about processing the request on given platform (C). What I needed to have is some translating component, the middle layer (B).

Comment: I didn't want A know anything about C. I wanted the A component to only be aware of tag and a list of parameters. But I think I didn't achieve this fully because if the list of parameters of methods of C changes then the A component would also be affected.

Comment: @YotKay I suggest you extend your mcve to give an example of how `A` behaves. How does it get the tags? How does it choose which parameters to pass to `B`? Because as it stands I still don't understand how `A` knowing about the names of the members of `B` is any different from `A` knowing about the tags and the choice of parameters it must pass to `B`. In my answer `A` does not need to be aware of `C`, that is hidden, only the types of function held by `B`.